# ASP.NET MVC Custom route regex to catch a substring of items and check for their existence

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to create a custom route for URL with the following format:

> http://domain/nodes/{item_1}/{item_2}/{item3_}/..../{item_[n]}

Basically, there could be a random amount of item_[n], for example

```
http://domain/nodes/1/3/2 

http://domain/nodes/1

http://domain/nodes/1/25/11/45
```

With my custom route I would like to retrieve an array of items and do some logic (validate and add some specific information to request context) with them.

For example from [http://domain/nodes/1/25/11/45] I would like to get an array of [1, 25, 11, 45] and process it.

So, I have 2 problems here.

The first one is a question actually. Am I looking in the right direction? Or there could be an easier way to accomplish this (maybe without custom routes)?

The second problem is matching incoming url with a regex pattern. Could someone help me with it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem I think that a way could be to create a routing class and then handle the params accordinlgy.

```
  public class CustomRouting : RouteBase
  {
     public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
     {
       RouteData result = null;
       var repository = new FakeRouteDB(); //Use you preferred DI injector
       string requestUrl = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
       string[] sections = requestUrl.Split('/');
       /*
       from here you work on the array you just created
       you can check every single part
       */
       if (sections.Count() == 2 && sections[1] == "")
         return null; // ~/

       if (sections.Count() > 2) //2 is just an example
       {
         result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
         result.Values.Add("controller", "Products");
         result.Values.Add("action", "Edit");
         result.Values.Add("itmes0", sections[1]);
         if (sections.Count() >= 3)
         result.Values.Add("item2", sections[2]);
         //....
       }
       else
       {
         //I can prepare a default route        
         result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
         result.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
         result.Values.Add("action", "Index");
       }
       return result;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
     //I just work with outbound so it's ok here to do nothing
     return null;
    }
}
```

In the global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.Add(new CustomRouting());

  routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

This should give you an idea of what I think. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the first part of your question, but I can have a go at creating the regex.

In your example all the items are digits - is that the only option ? If not, please provide more info on possible characters.

For now the regex would be:

```
@"http://domain/nodes(?:/(\d+))*"
```

`(?:)` is a non capturing group, `()` is a capturing group.
If you match all occurences, then you'll end up with groups `1-n`, where each group will contain the matched number (group number 0 will be the whole match).